# Ant-design TimePicker - "popupClassName" prop is not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, antd

I have been using the timepicker and trying to customize the popup for which I might need to add a class to the popup . I tried using "popupClassName" but i don't see that class name getting added to the popup.

Kindly let me know how can i add a class to the timepicker popup .

Answer (score 1):

It does work as documented. See https://codepen.io/JesperWe/pen/RVOwOV which adds a class and some CSS to give the popup a red shadow.

```
<TimePicker defaultValue={moment()} popupClassName="foobar"/>
```

result:

```
<div class="ant-time-picker-panel foobar ant-time-picker-panel-column-3 ant-time-picker-panel-placement-bottomLeft"
     style="left: 24px; top: 63.7778px;">
    <div class="ant-time-picker-panel-inner">
        <div class="ant-time-picker-panel-input-wrap">
            <input class="ant-time-picker-panel-input" value="02:32:41" placeholder="Select time"><a
                class="ant-time-picker-panel-clear-btn" role="button" title="clear"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="ant-time-picker-panel-combobox">
            <div class="ant-time-picker-panel-select">
                <ul>...</ul>
            </div>
            <div class="ant-time-picker-panel-select">
                <ul>...</ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah its working , Thanks. My mistake, I update the antD verion to 2.10.2 and it worked. But i have one more question regarding the time picker . Is there a we can stop the scrolltop when we choose a time .